What should the base value be for energy when using a per unit model for a power system?
What should the base value be for energy when using a per unit model for a power system?  Normally, I would fix \$s_{\textrm{base}}\$ and \$v_{\textrm{base}}\$ and use that to determine \$i_{\textrm{base}}\$ and \$z_{\textrm{base}}\$, then transform from SI units to per unit.  However, I'd also like to model the amount of energy in an energy storage device, which is the integral over time of power.  If the power into and out of the energy storage device is in pu, then its integral has units pu-s, which is awkward and potentially large.  Is there a good way to model energy in per unit terms as well?

Can you give more context if what kind of modeling you are doing?

I'm modeling the impact of energy storage on the grid.  To that end, I'd like to take one of the published models of a power system, which are in per unit form, and add some energy storage.  However, I'd like to look at energy in the device and not just power in/out.

The numbers are going to be big because grid-scale energy storage involves large quantities. If you don't want to use watts and joules for whatever reason, you can still use metric prefixes or powers of 10.

If you're modelling it on a computer, use SI units as the maths just works with no strange scaling factors.  The computer won't care if the numbers get very big if you use double-precision floats.
On the output, you could convert to kilowatt-hours or megawatt-hours to make it more human-friendly.
